# What is the shortest path that visits every node and edge in the dodecahedral graph?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

The dodecahedral graph is the Platonic graph corresponding to the connectivity of the vertices of a dodecahedron, with 20 nodes and 30 edges. Assuming all edges have a length (weight) of 1, I want to find the shortest path that

- visits every node at least once,
- traverses every edge at least once (regardless of direction),
- never traverses the same edge twice in a row (must visit other edges before returning)
- starts and ends at the same node.

[image: Image of the dodecahedral graph projected onto a flat plane]

There are thirty edges, so covering all of them requires a path length of at least 30. I know that because each node is connected to three edges, at least one of those edges must be traversed more than once to cover all three. However, I don't know *how many* edges need to be double-counted, or if any need to be triple-counted (or more).

Is there a good way to figure this out besides brute-force checking all possible paths?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_postman_problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an initial observation, as each vertex will need to be visited at least twice (at most two edges are used on first visit, so a second visit is necessary to use the third edge) so a clear lower bound would be that it needs at least 40 steps.

As a second observation, if you add ten more edges where each vertex was involved in exactly one of the newly added edges, then the graph becomes 4-regular and thus eulerian (*has a circuit which uses each edge exactly once*).

As a final observation, if we could find a perfect cover, those ten edges to be added could simply duplicate the edges used in the perfect cover.  Indeed, trying to find a perfect cover in a greedy fashion is not difficult.

[image]

As all vertices in the graph with duplicated edges have even degree, there exists a eulerian circuit here that uses each edge exactly once and is therefore of length $40$.

This circuit corresponds to a circuit in the original graph where we simply reuse edges where we would otherwise have traveled along a parallel edge.  Since we knew we needed at least $40$ steps, this proves that such a eulerian circuit is optimal.

---

Included now is also an explicit example of a circuit that further avoids reusing a particular edge twice in succession.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of an Eulerian circuit on the modified form of the graph in your answer? I've tried following the algorithms described on Wikipedia by hand, but can't figure out how to get a circuit with the symmetry of your picture.

Comment: @Lawton Call the duplicated edges and the edge they duplicate "red" for convenience and the rest black.  Start at a point of your choosing.  There will be two black edges to choose from.  Choose one to begin your circuit.  From here out, once arriving at a new vertex, travel along the red edge and immediately return back at first opportunity if those red edges haven't been used yet.  Afterwards, travel along the next black edge.  Repeat until the circuit is complete.

Comment: @Lawton if I start labeling the outermost layer starting from north and going clockwise as A,B,C,D,E, and then the next inner layer starting from north and going clockwise as a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i... and finally the innermost layer starting at the northeast position as 1,2,3,4,5... our circuit begins as ABCBcdcbab151232defeC...

Comment: Your response made me realize I have an additional constraint that I hadn't consciously considered and therefore didn't include in my question before: I can't traverse the same edge twice in a row. How much does that change things?

Comment: It does change things insofar as our theorems won't guarantee us such a path.  (*Consider a "pinched cycle"*).  That said, everything said thus far is still valid.  $40$ remains an easy lower bound, and when trying to find a greedy circuit through the graph with duplicated edges... for it to avoid immediately reusing the parallel edges would (*as each vertex is degree 4*) require us to alternate between using a parallel edge and a non-parallel edge (*noting we could never use two different parallel edges consecutively since they came from a perfect matching/cover*)

Comment: @Lawton I've included an explicit example of a circuit in an image above following the strategy of alternating between a edge that has a parallel and an edge which doesn't.